# How do you compile the precompiled in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was handed a "precompiled" asp.net app source code. OK, how do I make this such that I can use and debug it?  How do I compile a precompiled app?

[image: http://i67.photobucket.com/albums/h292/Athono/precompiled_zps65b526bf.png]

After I click past this window, and i try to build the application, I get an error that says "This application is already precompiled".

What can I do?

Comment: Telerik JustDecompile is a free .NET decompiler : http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608587/decompile-precompiled-source-code-asp-net

Comment: This appears to be a web site (created with File->New web site), not a project (created with file->new project).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A precompiled application has already had it's code (C#) compiled into DLLs.  There are a few options with ASP.NET precompilation that may allow you to update the site, but it will be difficult to change any of the C# with a precompiled version.  If the site was precompiled with the "Updateable" flag set to true, you can update .aspx (Web Forms) and .ascx (User Control) files.  You don't need to do a full build for these updates to show on your site, just Save them and view in browser.

If updateable was NOT set to true, these files will have all also been compiled into DLLs and there isn't much you can do.  If you just need to look at the code and not update anything, there's a way to find which DLLs each .aspx and .ascx was compiled to and you can use reflection (.NET Reflector or similar) to investigate further.

The reason you get the error is because the site has already been compiled and therefore can't be recompiled.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get the source code for that project and open it in visual studio.  If you don't have VS installed, you will need to do that.  After you have VS open go to File -> Open Web Site.  Then select "File System", browse to the location of your web site and click open.

That should do it.

Comment: I have the source code.  I am running this in Visual studio.  When I click to rebuild the web site there is an error in the Error list that says "Thie applicaton is alreay precompiled".  it is not a problem with not havnig the source code.  I have all the .aspx DND THE .ASPX.CS code.  Do I need to delete the dlls?

Comment: Check if there is a PrecompiledApp.config file where your source code is and delete it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to debug/look/change the source code you will need to decompile the files. Take a look at .NET reflector or other decompiler.