# Recovering .net project from precompiled code

Tags: .net, telerik, decompiling, decompiler, precompile

Somehow I lost my source project, but I have it in the form of a pre-compiled project hosted on my server. I tried to use a decompiler. I am able to see code files, but the problem is that I am not able to recover or read the asp.net server page. When I open them the only thing I see is "This is a marker file generated by the pre-compilation tool, and should not be deleted!"

Even if I recover all code files how can I recover page files? I mean the markup language files. Also, how I will re house them together to generate a new project?

I see in the bin folder all the .aspx pages are in the form of compiled files with their respective name

I am currently using Telerik's decompiler.

Comment: I would recommend going to your backup and starting from there.

Comment: No backup files . everything is lost from our local code server.

Comment: i have all aspx files in compiled form? how can i decompile them?

Comment: Sorry to hear your circumstance. Before moving on to something more exotic, try any number of (deleted-but-not-overwritten) file-recovery tools on a USB stick or a SD card (so as not to ironically overwrite the your target file(s) with the download or installation).

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608587/decompile-precompiled-source-code-asp-net

Comment: we have tried all solution ? does anyone know what i am asking?we have only way to do it from decompiler.

Comment: I've had to do what you need many times in my career. My previous recovery-tool suggestion is where I think you should start.  Otherwise, getting clearer about your exact instance of this class of problem is key.  Do you know the version of VS that produced the live site based in the lost code?  The the related projects and their project types?  A lot of what to ask...depends.

Comment: its based on .net framework 2

Comment: i am able to see the compiled aspx file and its code but when i export it to project it convert the aspx file to .cs file? how can i make it aspx page instead of .cs file

Comment: I think there is no aspx page(markup file) . all i get is only code.. where are my aspx pages ?

Comment: aspx pages are not compiled into assemblies.