# How to get html markup of aspnet compiled file

Tags: asp.net

I've published my ASP.NET website to my Hosting Server via Visual Studio.

But things happened, and I lost all of my sources. I had a backup but it is not recent enough. I could re-code everything that is missing but I don't remember all of it.

I recovered some of my source code using ***JustDecompile*** tool but failed to recover the .aspx html markup code, When I open the aspx files, I can only see "This is a marker file generated by the precompilation tool, and should not be deleted!"

I was wondering if it's possible to get the aspnet markup code from the server where I published my website ? I have a full access on it.

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decompile Precompiled Source Code ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608587/decompile-precompiled-source-code-asp-net)

Comment: Looking ASPNET HTML Markup not the source code.

Comment: You _could_ either (a) go to each page with a browser to see the _rendered_ html (view source) and save, or, (b) automate  by writing a console app or use `curl`, `postman`, etc. to make `GET` requests - and save the HTML, etc. response.

Comment: Thanks EdSF, I did it.